# JSON Schema - how to reference enum value and combine multiple sets of enums to one property?

Tags: jsonschema

I have two enum fields in a schema:

```
{ ...
  "prop1": {
    oneOf": [{
      "enum": [
        "VAL1",
        "VAL2"],
      "type": "string"
      },{
        "type": "null"}]
  },
  "prop2": {
    oneOf": [{
      "enum": [
        "VAL3",
        "VAL4"],
      "type": "string"
      },{
        "type": "null"}]
}
```

I want to create a third enum field `prop3`, and to allow values from `prop1` and `prop2`.
I can copy the values:

```
{ ...
  "prop3": {
    oneOf": [{
      "enum": [
        "VAL1",
        "VAL2"
        "VAL3",
        "VAL4"
        ],
      "type": "string"
      },{
        "type": "null"}]
  }
}
```

but I want `prop3` to automaticly get new values when I aadd them to `prop1` or `prop2`.

Can I create a `definition` for enum values and then use it in two places?
How can I join two sets of enums like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `anyOf` keyword to effectively combine the enums.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "prop1": { "$ref": "#/definitions/prop1" },
    "prop2": { "$ref": "#/definitions/prop2" },
    "prop3": { "$ref": "#/definitions/prop3" }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "prop1": { "enum": ["VAL1", "VAL2"] },
    "prop2": { "enum": ["VAL3", "VAL4"] },
    "prop3": {
      "anyOf": [
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/prop1" },
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/prop2" }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```